# Let F0 = 0, F1 = 1, F2 = 1, . . ., F99 be the first 100 Fibonacci numbers (recall that Fn = Fn−1 + Fn−2 for n ≥ 2).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

Let F0 = 0, F1 = 1, F2 = 1, . . ., F99 be the first 100 Fibonacci numbers (recall that Fn = Fn−1 + Fn−2 for n ≥ 2). how many of them are divisible by 3

Comment: Look at the remainders of the first 10 or 12, after you divide them by 3, and see if you see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
F_0 &\equiv 0 \mod{3} \\
F_1 &\equiv 1 \mod{3} \\
F_2 &\equiv 1 \mod{3} \\
F_3 &\equiv 2 \mod{3} \\
F_4 &\equiv 0 \mod{3} \\
F_5 &\equiv 2 \mod{3} \\
F_6 &\equiv 2 \mod{3} \\
F_7 &\equiv 1 \mod{3} \\
F_8 &\equiv 0 \mod{3} \text{ Pattern repeats here}\\
F_9 &\equiv 1 \mod{3} \\
F_{10} &\equiv 1 \mod{3} \\
F_{11} &\equiv 2 \mod{3} \\
F_{12} &\equiv 0 \mod{3} \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: To prove the repeat, note that there are only $3$ residues $\bmod 3$, so there are only $3^2=9$ potential pairs of residues.  If we make the recurrence $\bmod 3$ it must repeat within $3^2=9$ elements.

Comment: so that would mean that there is 11 numbers that are divisible by 3 to 100